# How Do Laravel Spark Forms Submit?

Tags: forms, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

Laravel Spark has a number of forms in its settings area.  Here's one that adds teams.

[image]

If I look at the source code of this form, I see the following.

The HTML source for this form looks like the following

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Team Name
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="create-team-name" name="name" class="form-control">
<!---->
                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Create 
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Specifically, the form itself has no `action` or `type` parameter

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
```

My assumption is there's some javascript running that handles all this (a Vue JS component), but it's not clear

1. Where the Team Creation javascript source lives, and/or where Spark creates the component
2. How I can backtrack how a particular form to its javascript

Experienced programmer here -- just new to Spark and hoping this is simple/obvious for an experienced Spark developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `<form>` in Spark is typically handled by a Vue.js component containing its definition, and although they don't have `action` or `method` attributes, they *do* have special Vue directives, such as `@submit` (or `@click` if it's a `<button type="submit">`). The reason you don't see them in HTML in dev tools, is because those directives are compiled before rendering.

So the form you're referring to is wrapped into a `<spark-create-team>` tag. You can find the code that initializes this component in `/resources/assets/js/spark-components/settings/teams/create-team.js`; you'll also note that it simply requires the component definition from Spark's `/vendor` directory. In other words, **component and form definitions are stored in Spark vendor files** at `/vendor/laravel/spark/resources/assets/js/settings/teams/create-form.js`. Can you see that `settings/teams/create-form.js` part is identical? This should help you locate the underlying JS code for any component or form -- just search Spark's JS assets, and eventually its folder structure will become a second nature to you.

As for the `SparkForm` class, it's a [helper class designed for working with form errors](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/forms). Its definition is in `vendor/laravel/spark/resources/assets/js/forms/form.js` file, although I don't think you'll ever need to make any modifications to it; just follow Taylor's examples with forms using Axios, and you shouldn't have any problems with submissions or validation. Although for the later point, validation, I'd suggest using an [external package](https://m.dotdev.co/form-validation-using-vue-js-2-35abd6b18c5d), instead of defaulting to server-side validation, but that's a bit off topic here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I was looking for

Comment: Re: just follow Taylor's examples with forms using Axios -- which examples are these?

Comment: @AlanStorm Just about any component example in vendor files with a `SparkForm` in it, to see how forms are submitted. Or you can simply refer to the docs (link in the answer).

Comment: Ah, got it @alex, thank you.  I thought you were referring to a specific tutorial that's well known in the laravel world.  Thanks again for your help!